# Calculate the optimal Resolution Parameter for Leiden Community Detection algorithm

Tags: r, object-detection, modularity, leiden

I need a method viable to pre-determine the Resolution Parameter in Leiden algorithm for Community detection, using the "Modularity" objective function (instead of CPM). I read several documents but couldn't find a consistent way to implement it in R code. Anyone has encountered a similar challenge?

I tried to manually adjust the Resolution Parameter and finally I decided to make the algorithm find the parameter automatically, disabling the resolution parameter and the vertex weight, as specified in the documentation, but wanted to find a more accurate way. Here's the code I used.

```
communities_auto <- cluster_leiden(graph2, 
                          objective_function = "modularity", 
                          weights = E(graph2)$weight,
                          (#)resolution_parameter = 1.05
                          n_iterations = 1000)
```